# Issues after cloning old SSD to new SSD

Tags: partitioning, gparted, ssd, disk, disk-usage

I've spent a day fixing issues after having `dd` cloned my old SSD to my new SSD.  My old SSD was a 160 GB , and the new one is 250 GB..  Cloning the old one to the new one caused the partition table to cloned as well meaning I would have 90 GB unallocated space.

I then via `Gparted` the allocated the unallocated with `/dev/sda2` which then made `/dev/sda2` 250 GB.  Problem now is when I open the filesystem, and check how much space is available, I only see 150 GB... instead of 250 GB?... The space is allocated correctly on the new SSD, I am able to boot from it, but it looks like the filesystem is not on the ssd but somewhere else?

[image]

how do i utilize the full space on my ssd?
Added extra info:

output from `lsblk`

```
lsblk
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                            8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1                         8:1    0   243M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                         8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5                         8:5    0 232.7G  0 part 
  ├─ubuntu--vg-root (dm-0)   252:0    0 140.9G  0 lvm  /
  └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 (dm-1) 252:1    0     8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb                            8:16   0 698.7G  0 disk 
└─sdb1                         8:17   0 698.7G  0 part /media/mai/40163a7
sdc                            8:32   1  14.7G  0 disk 
└─sdc1                         8:33   1  14.7G  0 part
```

output from `sudo parted -l`

```
sudo parted -l
[sudo] password for mai: 
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  256MB  255MB  primary   ext2         boot
 2      257MB   250GB  250GB  extended
 5      257MB   250GB  250GB  logical                lvm


Model: ATA WDC WD7500BPVT-2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 750GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  750GB  750GB  primary  ext4


Model: Kingston HyperX Fury 3.0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 15.7GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  15.7GB  15.7GB  fat32        Microsoft Basic Data  boot


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 8540MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  8540MB  8540MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 151GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  151GB  151GB  ext4
```

LVM visual view:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the outputs of the terminal commands `lsblk` and `sudo parted -l` to your question please?

Comment: added @ByteCommander

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've increased the physical partition size, now you've got to use LVM to increase the logical partition size.

Easiest to install `system-config-lvm` to visually help you...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install system-config-lvm
```

Start it from the Unity dash by typing `lvm` into the search box.

**Update #1:**

Change the logical view for root. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm for basic help. You can also search https://help.ubuntu.com for "system-config-lvm" and find a lot more detailed help.

Comment: I am no sure what to do in `lvm`... i added a gui image of what i see..

Comment: Change the "logical view" for "root". See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm for help. You can also search https://help.ubuntu.com for system-config-lvm and find a lot more detailed help.